# Is there a way to customize Github checks with CircleCI?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, circleci

I am currently working on the CI of project and I deploy a preview for each github branch that pass all integration tests.

My CI workflow is executed by CircleCI and I can see the progression on github with [Github checks](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/enable-checks/). It works pretty nice but description does not reflect what really happens.

For instance I can see this on github :

[image: github_checks]

My problem is I would like to custom message and details actions link. My last job deploys a preview and I would like to be able to put the link somewhere. The best case should be able to open my preview when I click on details button.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I send a mail to CircleCI support and I got this anwser :

> Hello,
>
> It is not possible at this time to customize this text. Clicking the
>   details link will bring you to the job on CircleCI. We are currently
>   working on a utility that will allow you to post comments to the PR
>   from within a job that may be close to what you are looking for. This
>   will exist in an Orb (https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/) but I could
>   not say exactly how long until this is released, though we are
>   actively working on it.
>
> You may wish to post to our public facing ideas portal:
>   https://ideas.circleci.com/ideas as a new idea post. This will let our
>   community vote for this request. Please let us know if we can assist
>   any further.

So, unfortunately it is not possible yet. Maybe in the future.

Comment: Thomas - did Circle ever get back to you with any updates on this orb? Looks like this might be a relevant "idea" https://ideas.circleci.com/ideas/CCI-I-1050?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have an update since my question was asked. Looks like relevant I'll up. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not within CircleCI but this can be done using the Github Commit Statuses REST API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to enable third party orbs then [this orb](https://github.com/samsalisbury/orb-github-status) might be the answer which enables custom status for every jobs, you can tweak it.

> Note: Personally I do not like to integrate third party orbs in company projects, but if you wish to... you can.